# Zookeeper's 3888 listen on localhost if using hostname instead of IP

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, distributed-computing

If in zookepeer's config I set the servers as:

```
clientPort=2181
server.1=kafka-test-01:2888:3888
server.2=kafka-test-02:2888:3888
server.3=kafka-test-03:2888:3888
```

where `kafka-test-0X` is an instance, and domain resolution is possible from any instance, I'm noticing that Zookeeper's port is listening on 127.0.1.1. And in fact, as it's not possible to communicate via 3888, the "leader port" 2888 isn't listening either.

```
tcp6       0      0 127.0.1.1:3888          :::*                    LISTEN      26951/java
```

However, if instead of the hostnames, I use the actual IP, for example:

```
server.1=192.168.0.11:2888:3888
server.2=192.168.0.12:2888:3888
server.3=192.168.0.13:2888:3888
```

it's listening just fine on each IP, and can connect from one to the other.

```
tcp6       0      0 192.168.0.13:2888       :::*                    LISTEN      26926/java
tcp6       0      0 192.168.0.13:3888       :::*                    LISTEN      26926/java
```

I've seen plenty of examples using hostnames, and even the official [documentation](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.1.2/zookeeperStarted.html) uses hostnames, so what might be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the following entry from the **/etc/hosts** file

```
127.0.1.1 kafka-test-01
```

then restart your zookeeper cluster.

Before zookeeper restart

```
]# netstat -tunlp | grep 3888
tcp6       0      0 127.0.1.1:3888          :::*                    LISTEN      23512/java
```

After zookeeper restart

```
netstat -tunlp | grep 3888
tcp6       0      0 <SERVER_IP>:3888        :::*                    LISTEN      30103/java
```

Answer (score 0):

this might be because in your /etc/hosts you might have your hostname against 127.0.0.1 comment it out as below
#127.0.1.1    < your hostname>

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned that's probably because your hostnames resolve to the loopback address instead of real IPs.